# Please explain this example of Prolog recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm learning Prolog and I'm having a hard time with recursion. The simple cases with a database I can understand, but I can't follow this exercise, where `redu/2` is implemented, which will remove the duplicates of a given list and give the new list as second argument:

```
redu([],[]).

redu([H|T], Result):-
  member(H,T),
  redu(T,Result).

redu([H|T], [H|Result]):-
   redu(T, Result).
```

A trace gives me this:

```
[trace]  ?- redu([a,b,b,c,a], X).
   Call: (8) redu([a, b, b, c, a], _35630) ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:member(a, [b, b, c, a]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member(a, [b, b, c, a]) ? creep
   Call: (9) redu([b, b, c, a], _35630) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(b, [b, c, a]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:member(b, [b, c, a]) ? creep
   Call: (10) redu([b, c, a], _35630) ? creep
   Call: (11) lists:member(b, [c, a]) ? creep
   Fail: (11) lists:member(b, [c, a]) ? creep
   Redo: (10) redu([b, c, a], _35630) ? creep
   Call: (11) redu([c, a], _35900) ? creep
   Call: (12) lists:member(c, [a]) ? creep
   Fail: (12) lists:member(c, [a]) ? creep
   Redo: (11) redu([c, a], _35900) ? creep
   Call: (12) redu([a], _35906) ? creep
   Call: (13) lists:member(a, []) ? creep
   Fail: (13) lists:member(a, []) ? creep
   Redo: (12) redu([a], _35906) ? creep
   Call: (13) redu([], _35912) ? creep
   Exit: (13) redu([], []) ? creep
   Exit: (12) redu([a], [a]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) redu([c, a], [c, a]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) redu([b, c, a], [b, c, a]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) redu([b, b, c, a], [b, c, a]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) redu([a, b, b, c, a], [b, c, a]) ? creep
X = [b, c, a]
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could explain to me in natural language what recursion does and how to read the clauses. Like with the second clause, is it right that it reads as "remove duplicates from list `H|T` and output `Result` if the head of that list is a member of the tail and remove the duplicates from the tail and output the result? But how can the two `Results` be the same? And I also don't get which rule is activated when. When does it go forward in my list of clauses? When does it go back?

Sorry for all the questions. I really want to understand everything.

Comment: your edit radically changes the question, and invalidates the answers. We are not supposed to do that on SO, so I'm going to roll it back.

Answer (score 0):

Any recursive implementation has at least two clauses - base clauses, and oone or more recursive clauses.

Base clauses deal with degenerate cases: empty lists, zeros, and so on. They give simple answers - for example, in your case the base clause states that the answer for an empty list is an empty list.

The recursive clauses deal separately with a situation when the item is on the list (second clause), and when the item is not on the list (third clause). The second clause says that when an item is found on the tail portion of the list (member of T) then it should not be added to the result now; it will be added later. If, on the other hand, this is the last item, third clause adds it to the output list.

> But then, eventually, the member check will fail (`b` is not a member of `[c,a]`), but how does it work then?

Once member check fails, Prolog goes to the third clause, which adds `H` to the output list with `[H|Result]`, and proceeds to computing the rest of the `Result` from the tail part `T` of the list with `redu(T, Result)`.

**Note 1:** There is one mistake in the program, though: the last clause needs to be conditioned on the item *not* being on the tail portion of the list:

```
redu([H|T], [H|Result]):-
   \+ member(H,T),
   redu(T, Result).
```

This should prevent Prolog from going into the clause if the second clause has executed.

**Note 2:** The other option is to use cut in the second clause, but this option is highly discouraged.

Comment: Okay, so I get it when there are duplicates: if the membercheck succeeds, the redu(T, Result) rule is activated and after that prolog re-rolls to the beginning. The new list (which is the tail) is first matched with the first clause, but no match, it goes on to the second, there is a match and the membercheck is activated again. But then, eventually, the membercheck will fail (b is not a member of c,a), but how does it work then? Is de third part of the second clause activated again? Does it go back to the beginning? Is the whole second clause suddenly invalid?

Comment: @das there'll still be duplicates included though, in the *next* results after the first one -- there are no cuts in the code, nor mutually exclusive goals in co-matching clauses.

Comment: @WillNess You are right, I kind of assumed there's an exclamation in the second clause, but it's not there. Thank you very much for the comment!

Comment: `\+` is just as impure as `!`. besides, I think this question is more like "help me understand", not "help me implement".

Answer (score 0):

So you have

```erlang
redu([], []).
redu([H|T],    R ):- member(H, T), redu(T, R).
redu([H|T], [H|R]):-               redu(T, R).
==
redu([], []).
redu([H|T], X ):-   member(H, T), X =    R , redu(T, R).
redu([H|T], X):-                  X = [H|R], redu(T, R).
==
redu([], []).
redu([H|T], X ):- ( member(H, T), X =    R 
                    ;             X = [H|R]), redu(T, R).
==
redu([], []).
redu([H|T], X ):- disj(H, T, X, R), redu(T, R).

disj(H, T,    R,  R):- member(H, T).
disj(H,_T, [H|R], R).
```

These two new `redu/2` clauses are mutually exclusive, so the code can be easier to understand in this form. Whether `disj/4` includes `H` into the list `X` being built (in the top-down manner) or not - and however many times it succeeds (*) - after `disj/4` does its thing, the recursive call to `redu/2` is simply made.

So we read `redu(L,X)` as "*for the head element `H` in `L=[H|T]`, if there *are* some more `H`s in `T`, *either* don't include `H` in the 'output' list `X`, or do; and for a unique `H` - such that does not occur in `T` - include it in `X` always;* **and then**, having dealt with this head element `H` of `L`, proceed to deal with the rest of the elements in the list *in the same manner*." In other words, do *this* for *each* element in the list `L`.

This recursive definition follows naturally the inductive definitions of lists as **`[H|T]`** or **`[]`** structures.

(*) (do take note that **A.** `member` may succeed more than once, and **B.** the two clauses of `disj/4` are *not* mutually exclusive).

With your example,

```erlang
redu([a,b,b,c,a], X)
==
disj( a, [b,b,c,a], X,R),             %  AND  redu([b,b,c,a], R)   i.e.
    disj( b, [b,c,a], R,R2),            %  AND  redu([b,c,a], R2)  i.e.
        disj( b, [c,a], R2,R3),           %  AND  redu([c,a], R3)  i.e.
            disj( c, [a],  R3,R4),          %  AND  redu([a], R4)  i.e.
                disj( a, [],  R4,R5),         %  AND  the final clause,
                   redu( [],     R5).
```

Now you can try each `disj/4` invocation and see what is happening there, like

```erlang
33 ?- disj(a,[b,b,c,a], X,R).
X = R ;
X = [a|R].

34 ?- disj(b,[c,a], R2,R3).
R2 = [b|R3].
```

Thus the whole example becomes

```erlang
(X = R ; X = [a|R]),                          % [ a
    (R = R2 ; R = [b|R2]),                    %   b
         R2 = [b|R3],                         %   b
                 R3 = [c|R4],                 %   c
                         R4 = [a|R5],         %   a
                                 R5 = [].     % ]
```

or

```erlang
ex(X):-
 (X = R ; X = [a|R]), 
     (R = R2 ; R = [b|R2]), 
          R2 = [b,c,a].
```

which is

```erlang
42 ?- ex(X).
X = [b, c, a] ;
X = [b, b, c, a] ;
X = [a, b, c, a] ;
X = [a, b, b, c, a].
```